# What query should be written for this?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Hi I have a transaction table for customers of a bank. The name of the table is CUST_TRANSACTION.  It has a few fields like CUST_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE etc. I want to write a query so that I can select the last transaction for 3 particular customer ids. So for example

```
TRANSACTION_ID | CUST_ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | TRANSACTION_DESC

100023 | 2 | 15-12-2014 06:00 | Withdraw 1000 dollars
100022 | 5 | 14-12-2014 16:00 | Deposit 1000 dollars 
100021 | 5 | 14-12-2014 15:00 | Withdraw 500 dollars
100020 | 4 | 12-12-2014 15:00 | Withdraw 300 dollars
100019 | 4 | 12-12-2014 14:39 | Deposit 300 dollars
100018 | 2 | 12-12-2014 15:00 | Withdraw 60 dollars
```

I would want to get the last transactions for ids 2,4,5

```
TRANSACTION_ID | CUST_ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | TRANSACTION_DESC

100023 | 2 | 15-12-2014 06:00 | Withdraw 1000 dollars
100022 | 5 | 14-12-2014 16:00 | Deposit 1000 dollars
100020 | 4 | 12-12-2014 15:00 | Withdraw 300 dollars
```

How should I approach it?

**EDIT**: So far I have tried this

```
select * 
from CUST_TRANSACTION 
where CUST_ID IN('2', '5', '4') 
and rownum <4 
order by transaction_date desc
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at this? Sounds like you want us to do your work for you. Sounds a lot like a homework question. According to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @mason Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rank() to get the top item, then select just the top-ranked row for each.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select 
    transaction_id,
    cust_id,
    transaction_date,
    transaction_desc,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cust_id, transaction_date desc) AS rank_id
  from cust_transaction
  ) ct
WHERE ct.rank_id = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c67c1/3).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck for a long time. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
SELECT CUST_ID , a.TRANSACTION_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE , TRANSACTION_DESC from CUST_TRANSACTION AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID FROM CUST_TRANSACTION GROUP BY CUST_ID) AS b ON a.TRANSACTION_ID=b.TRANSACTION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.TRANSACTION_ID , 
t1.CUST_ID ,t1.TRANSACTION_DATE ,t1.TRANSACTION_DESC from table t1 
inner join
(
select CUST_ID ,min(TRANSACTION_DATE) as  TRANSACTION_DATE from table
group by CUST_ID
) t2
on t1.CUST_ID=t2.CUST_ID and t1.TRANSACTION_DATE =t2.TRANSACTION_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by on customer id and get max(transaction_date). Get records with this customer id and transaction_date combination